# How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm writing a function that could return several one of several different errors.

```
fn foo(...) -> Result<..., MyError> {}
```

I'll probably need to define my own error type to represent such errors. I'm presuming it would be an `enum` of possible errors, with some of the `enum` variants having diagnostic data attached to them:

```
enum MyError {
    GizmoError,
    WidgetNotFoundError(widget_name: String)
}
```

Is that the most idiomatic way to go about it? And how do I implement the `Error` trait?

Comment: I suppose you already read the [relevant section from the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html#defining-your-own-error-type). :) But given the multiple error boilerplate crates out there, answers might wish to expand on more than just this entry.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/multiple_error_types/define_error_type.html

Comment: See also [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror), and [this blog post](https://nick.groenen.me/posts/rust-error-handling/).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You implement [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) exactly like you would [any other trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html); there's nothing extremely special about it:

```
pub trait Error: Debug + Display {
    fn description(&self) -> &str { /* ... */ }
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&Error> { /* ... */ }
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(Error + 'static)> { /* ... */ }
}
```

`description`, `cause`, and `source` all have default implementations<sup>1</sup>, and your type must also implement `Debug` and `Display`, as they are supertraits.

```
use std::{error::Error, fmt};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Thing;

impl Error for Thing {}

impl fmt::Display for Thing {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Oh no, something bad went down")
    }
}
```

Of course, what `Thing` contains, and thus the implementations of the methods, is highly dependent on what kind of errors you wish to have. Perhaps you want to include a filename in there, or maybe an integer of some kind. Perhaps you want to have an `enum` instead of a `struct` to represent multiple types of errors.

If you end up wrapping existing errors, then I'd recommend implementing `From` to convert between those errors and your error. That allows you to use `try!` and `?` and have a pretty ergonomic solution.

> Is that the most idiomatic way to go about it?

Idiomatically, I'd say that a library will have a small (maybe 1-3) number of primary error types that are exposed. These are likely to be enumerations of other error types. This allows consumers of your crate to not deal with an explosion of types. Of course, this depends on your API and whether it makes sense to lump some errors together or not.

Another thing to note is that when you choose to embed data in the error, that can have wide-reaching consequences. For example, the standard library doesn't include a filename in file-related errors. Doing so would add overhead to every file error. The caller of the method usually has the relevant context and can decide if that context needs to be added to the error or not.

---

I'd recommend doing this by hand a few times to see how all the pieces go together. Once you have that, you will grow tired of doing it manually. Then you can check out crates which provide macros to reduce the boilerplate:

- [error-chain](https://crates.io/crates/error-chain)
- [failure](https://crates.io/crates/failure)
- [quick-error](https://crates.io/crates/quick-error)
- [Anyhow](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow)
- [SNAFU](https://crates.io/crates/snafu)

My preferred library is SNAFU (because I wrote it), so here's an example of using that with your original error type:

```
use snafu::prelude::*; // 0.7.0

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum MyError {
    #[snafu(display("Refrob the Gizmo"))]
    Gizmo,
    #[snafu(display("The widget '{widget_name}' could not be found"))]
    WidgetNotFound { widget_name: String },
}

fn foo() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    WidgetNotFoundSnafu {
        widget_name: "Quux",
    }
    .fail()
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = foo() {
        println!("{}", e);
        // The widget 'Quux' could not be found
    }
}
```

Note I've removed the redundant `Error` suffix on each enum variant. It's also common to just call the type `Error` and allow the consumer to prefix the type (`mycrate::Error`) or rename it on import (`use mycrate::Error as FooError`).

---

<sup>1</sup> Before [RFC 2504](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2504-fix-error.md) was implemented, `description` was a required method.

Comment: Thanks for another detailed, helpful answer -- especially the suggestion about starting by rolling-your-own and then moving to some crates to reduce boilerplate. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 15):

The crate [custom_error](https://crates.io/crates/custom_error) allows the definition of custom error types with less boilerplate than what was proposed above:

```
custom_error!{MyError
     Io{source: io::Error}             = "input/output error",
     WidgetNotFoundError{name: String} = "could not find widget '{name}'",
     GizmoError                        = "A gizmo error occurred!"
}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this crate.

Answer (score 5):

> Is that the most idiomatic way to go about it? And how do I implement the Error trait?

It's a common way, yes. "idiomatic" depends on how strongly typed you want your errors to be, and how you want this to interoperate with other things.

> And how do I implement the Error trait?

Strictly speaking, you don't need to here. You might for interoperability with other things that require `Error`, but since you've defined your return type as this enum directly, your code should work without it.