# Return value from main() in Rust doesn't work

Tags: rust

Been trying to write a function just to do this.

```
fn main() -> Result<i32, i32> {
    let clargs: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // validate command line arguments
    if clargs.len() != 3 {
        // clargs[0] is the name of the executable
        print_usage(&clargs[0]);
        return Err(1);
    }

    return Ok(0);
}

fn print_usage(exe_name: &String) {
    eprintln!("Usage: {exe_name} <word_file> <hash_sha1>");
}
```

I also tried this.

```
fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let clargs: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // validate command line arguments
    if clargs.len() != 3 {
        // clargs[0] is the name of the shacker1 executable
        print_usage(&clargs[0]);
        return Err("error: invalid number of arguments.");
    }

    return Ok(());
}

fn print_usage(exe_name: &String) {
    eprintln!("Usage: {exe_name} <word_file> <hash_sha1>");
}
```

But I can't figure out how to transform a string in to an error. Can't find it in the docs. Can't find examples.

How does one return anything like what I'm doing here?

Comment: Related: [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584368/11082165), [How to manually return a Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550167/how-to-manually-return-a-result-boxdyn-error), [learnrust.blog - Idiomatic Error Handling in Rust](https://www.learnrust.blog/p/idiomatic-error-handling-in-rust)

Comment: If you want to use a string, you can just make `main` return `Result<(), &'static str>`. Not sure where the `std::io::Error` struct is coming from - are you mixing that up with the `Error` trait?

Comment: Side-note: Look into `clap` and `clap_derive` when you get a chance. Nobody in any modern language should be hard-coding their usage statements separate from the actual parsing code, and while I haven't been doing Rust for very long, `clap` is one of the best things I've run into for simple command line utilities. Define a struct, annotate it with some basic info, and `clap` can write the rest for you, opening files, validating argument ranges, parsing switches, generating usage statements, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple possible ways to go about returning a specific error code from a Rust program.  One is to return *something* that implements the `Termination` trait.  That can be `ExitCode`, which represents an exit status; a `Result<T, E>` where `T` implements `Termination` and `E` implements `Debug`; or one of a few other things.

So, the simplest way to simply return a status code is this:

```
use std::env;
use std::process::ExitCode;

fn main() -> ExitCode {
    let clargs: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // validate command line arguments
    if clargs.len() != 3 {
        // clargs[0] is the name of the executable
        print_usage(&clargs[0]);
        return 2.into();
    }

    0.into()
}

fn print_usage(exe_name: &String) {
    eprintln!("Usage: {exe_name} <word_file> <hash_sha1>");
}
```

`ExitCode` implements `From<u8>`, so you can simply call `.into` on a `u8` and that will work.  Note that this gives you the most flexibility, because it allows you to return any unsuccessful status you want.

You can also do something like this (only `main` is shown):

```
fn main() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    let clargs: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // validate command line arguments
    if clargs.len() != 3 {
        // clargs[0] is the name of the executable
        print_usage(&clargs[0]);
        return Err("invalid number of arguments");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

That works because `&'static str` implements `Debug`.  Note that this will not give you as much control over the exit status, which may or may not be a problem.

Finally, you can simply call `std::process::exit`.  This can be done anywhere, but this shows how you might do it if you want (only `main` and `do_main` shown):

```
fn do_main() -> i32 {
    let clargs: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // validate command line arguments
    if clargs.len() != 3 {
        // clargs[0] is the name of the executable
        print_usage(&clargs[0]);
        return 2;
    }

    0
}

fn main() {
    std::process::exit(do_main());
}
```

Note that `i32` doesn't implement `Termination`, so you can't use `Result<i32, i32>` as the return type.  You could use `Result<ExitCode, i32>`, but that would print the error `i32`, which you probably wouldn't want, so simply returning `ExitCode` would be more along the lines of what you're going for.

Comment: Thank you. That clears up not only this question, but many others I’ve had.