# What is the most idiomatic way to merge two error types?

Tags: error-handling, rust, idioms

I have a type `Foo` whose methods may "raise" errors of an associated type `Foo::Err`.

```
pub trait Foo {
    type Err;
    
    fn foo(&mut self) -> Result<(), Self::Err>;
}
```

I have another trait `Bar` with a method intended to process a `Foo`. `Bar` may issue errors of its own (specified by an associated type `Bar::Err`), but it may also encounter errors generated by the `Foo` it is processing.

I can see two ways to do this, but I don't know which one would be the most idiomatic to Rust.

The first one embeds a result in a result:

```
pub trait Bar1 {
    type Err;
    
    fn bar<F: Foo>(&mut self, foo: F) -> Result<Result<F, F::Err>, Self::Err>;
}
```

The second one merges the two error types into a dedicated enum:

```
pub trait Bar2 {
    type Err;
    
    fn bar<F: Foo>(&mut self, foo: F) -> Result<F, Choice<F::Err, Self::Err>>;
}
```

The second one looks semantically cleaner, but creates some hurdles for handling the additional enum.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6bbca6cb7df8b1be7c7d8f75656e370b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Answer (score 16):

Typically you don't do a "merge", but instead use nested errors, like this.

```
enum IntError {
    Overflow,
    Underflow
}

enum StrError {
    TooLong,
    TooShort,
}

enum GenericError {
    Int(IntError),
    Str(StrError),
}

impl From<IntError> for GenericError {
    fn from(e: IntError) -> Self {
        GenericError::Int(e)
    }
}

impl From<StrError> for GenericError {
    fn from(e: StrError) -> Self {
        GenericError::Str(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my example wasn't clear; when I wrote about "merging the two error *types* into a dedicated enum", what I had in mind was exactly something like your `GenericError`. My question was: is this additional layer the right way to go, or should I rather use a result of result?...

Answer (score 6):

You should use a trait object [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html), and you return the first error that you encounter:

```
pub trait Bar {
    fn bar<F: Foo>(&mut self, foo: F) -> Result<F, Box<dyn Error>>;
}
```

or implement your trait like this:

```
impl Bar for MyType {
    type Err = Box<dyn Error>;

    fn bar<F: Foo>(&mut self, foo: F) -> Result<F, Self::Err>;
}
```

If you really want to have your two errors (but this is strange because one error suffices to make the process not ok), you can use a crate like [`failure`](https://crates.io/crates/failure) to create an "error trace".

As a general advice, you should not forget to use the traits from `std` to add more semantic to your code.

Comment: @trentcl Oh, you're right, Err is useless after that :P Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Good point about the Error trait, that's indeed something that I must use. And indeed, this opens the third option of returning a Box<dyn Error>. However, that option does not seem very useful for the caller. They can not match it agains different error variants to decide what to do next...

Comment: *use a crate like failure* — note that failure is deprecated. See [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584368/155423) for a list of selected alternatives.