# Correct way to use "?;" syntax with multiple error types?

Tags: rust

I'm finding myself with functions that use different sorts of errors, some of which come from `std` (or wherever) and some of which are mine. I want to use the `?` operator to reduce my general slog of overhead, but that's tricky when I have different types.

In the below code, `foo` can fail either with an `std::io::Error` error, or `MyError`.

```
use std::fs::File;
pub enum MyError {
    IO(std::io::Error),
    Custom(String),
}
impl From<std::io::Error> for MyError {
    fn from(value: std::io::Error) -> Self {
        MyError::IO(value)
    }
}

fn bar(fail: bool) -> Result<usize, MyError> {
    if fail {
        Err(MyError::Custom("Was told to fail".to_owned()))
    } else {
        Ok(42)
    }
}
pub fn foo(path: &str, fail: bool) -> Result<usize, MyError> {
    let file: File = File::open(path)?;
    let b: usize = bar(fail)?;
    Ok(b)
}
```

I was able to make it work by having `MyError` be an enum with a branch that wraps `std::io::Error`, but I don't like this approach. I also tried making `MyError` be a trait with an implementation for `std::io::Error`, but that didn't work because the return type would be dynamic and I'd have to mess with boxing/unboxing.

I don't like my solution for a few reasons, of which the most significant is that it seems like it will scale poorly as more error types float around. For instance, suppose I also have functions which can throw an `std::fmt::Error`, possibly in combination with the other two. If I just add that into `MyError`, a function which calls `foo` and tries to resolve errors will seem like `foo` can fail with `fmt` errors, which it can't. However, if I make different versions of `MyError` for every combination, that's worse - I'd need a different implementation of `MyError` for every combination of errors.

(On top of that, it just seems clunky with the extra wrapping and the fact that it's a hand-rolled implementation for what seems like a common problem.)

Is there a better way to go about this? I really want to say that `foo` can fail with a result that can be one of a statically known set of different errors, ideally while maintaining the concise `?` syntax.

I saw [What is the most idiomatic way to merge two error types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438988/what-is-the-most-idiomatic-way-to-merge-two-error-types) , which didn't seem encouraging, but my question is a bit more specific and I'm curious if a better solution has emerged in the intervening years.

Comment: I believe the enum-of-errors approach is considered idiomatic. But you can also look into the `thiserror` and `anyhow` crates.

Comment: If you have other functions that can throw other errors, you can either have a custom error type for each function, or a general error type for all functions. Both have advantages and disadvantages, and you have to choose. But if you don't want this approach, what do you _do_ want your error to look like?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ideally it would be a custom error type for each function, but implicitly generated such that I'm not stuck writing an exponentially large number of custom types and `From` implementations - something like a union type. I realize that's not a thing in Rust, but I was hoping there was some entirely other approach that I was missing.

Comment: The enum itself cannot be automatically generated, but you can generate the `From` and `Display` and `Error` impls with `thiserror`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are in general two ways to deal with this.

- An `enum`
- The `Error` trait abstraction

---

## The `enum` way

The advantage is that you keep type information; the disadvantage is that you need to specify each possible type manually.

This is the solution you currently have. Although I don't recommend implementing its traits manually, I'd rather recommend the more or less unofficial standard crate [`thiserror`](https://docs.rs/thiserror):

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error("IO Error")]
    IO(#[from] std::io::Error),
    #[error("Other Error")]
    Custom(String),
}
```

Note the `#[from]` tag, which will automatically generate the `From` impl for you.

---

## The `Error` trait abstraction way

Every error should implement the `Error` trait; if so, there are several ways to abstract over them.

The built-in way would be `Box<dyn Error>`, although it has some disadvantages. Most notably, it only allows the error to be passed through, but in many cases you want to add more information as it gets up through the call stack. Also, you loose all information about the actual type of the error. Hence, this way is recommended mostly for quick prototyping, it is probably not the correct way for production.

Here is how a `Box<dyn Error>` version would look:

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fs::File};

fn bar(fail: bool) -> Result<usize, String> {
    if fail {
        Err("Was told to fail".to_owned())
    } else {
        Ok(42)
    }
}
pub fn foo(path: &str, fail: bool) -> Result<usize, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file: File = File::open(path)?;
    let b: usize = bar(fail)?;
    Ok(b)
}
```

A more sophisticated way would be the use of wrapper crates, like [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow) or [`miette`](https://docs.rs/miette).

Here is an `anyhow` solution:

```rust
use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};
use std::fs::File;

fn bar(fail: bool) -> Result<usize> {
    if fail {
        Err(anyhow!("Was told to fail"))
    } else {
        Ok(42)
    }
}
pub fn foo(path: &str, fail: bool) -> Result<usize> {
    let file: File = File::open(path)?;
    let b: usize = bar(fail)?;
    Ok(b)
}
```

---

## My personal favourite

I personally, on my projects, usually go with a combination of `thiserror` and `miette`. This allows you to use `enums` when you need to know the exact type, but also allows you to abstract with the `Error` type.

I really like `miette` because with the `fancy` feature, it gives you really nice layered error messages.

Here are two ways to implement your situation in `miette`:

- `miette`'s `enum` way:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use thiserror::Error;

use miette::{Diagnostic, Result};

#[derive(Error, Diagnostic, Debug)]
enum MyError {
    #[error("IO Error")]
    IO(#[from] std::io::Error),
    #[error("Other Error")]
    Custom(String),
}

fn bar(fail: bool) -> Result<usize, MyError> {
    if fail {
        Err(MyError::Custom("Was told to fail".to_string()))
    } else {
        Ok(42)
    }
}

fn foo(path: &str, fail: bool) -> Result<usize, MyError> {
    let file: File = File::open(path)?;
    let b: usize = bar(fail)?;
    Ok(b)
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let value = foo("does_not_exist.txt", false)?;
    println!("{}", value);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
Error:   × IO Error
  ╰─▶ The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
```

- `miette`'s `Error` abstraction way:

```rust
use std::fs::File;

use miette::{bail, Context, IntoDiagnostic, Result};

fn bar(fail: bool) -> Result<usize> {
    if fail {
        bail!("Was told to fail")
    }

    Ok(42)
}

fn foo(path: &str, fail: bool) -> Result<usize> {
    let _file: File = File::open(path)
        .into_diagnostic()
        .wrap_err("Opening file failed")?;
    let b: usize = bar(fail)?;
    Ok(b)
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let value = foo("does_not_exist.txt", false)?;
    println!("{}", value);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
Error:   × Opening file failed
  ╰─▶ The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
```

Which one you choose is of course personal opinion.