# How can I use Result::expect to log a message before panicking?

Tags: logging, rust

[`Result::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) panics with the given message. However, I'd like to log before panicking. Assuming I have used [log](https://crates.io/crates/log) facade and an implementation, I'd like to do something as:

```rust
// a result called `result`
result.something_like_expect(|e| {
    // assuming `e` is an error instance and implements `Display`
    error!("An error happened: {}", e);
    // and panics here
});
```

Is there such a solution using Rust 1.39.0?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err ? note that panic on error is not robust code

Comment: Thanks for "robust code" comment. I am kinda new to Rust (while I'm not totally a beginner in programming). I am trying to understand it. Yes, I kinda guessed `panic` is not an overall good idea. I have also seen I can return `Result` from `main` but it does not comply with many types of errors in my codebase. So I thought using `panic` is better than nothing. Still waiting for other answers though, maybe someone provides a different perspective.

Comment: *but it does not comply with many types of errors in my codebase* — [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584368/155423)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use `map_err` with `unwrap`:

```
fn main() {
    let result: Result<(), String> = Err("error message".into());
    result.map_err(|e| log::error!("Failed with: {}", e)).unwrap();
}
```

But I recommend you to keep errors and just send them all upwards with `anyhow` crate:

```
use anyhow::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let result: Result<(), Error> = Err(Error::msg("error message"));
    let unwrapped_result = result?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Note that failure isn't the only such crate. You are encouraged to review the available libraries and choose one that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will look into crates about error handling.

Comment: I know that Shepmaster is author of `snafu`. Yes, you can use that crate too. It can derive custom errors. In case if you use `anyhow` you will need `thiserror` crate to derive custom error types.