# An elegant way of getting Result<T, E> based on Result<_, E1> and Result<T, E2>?

Tags: validation, input, error-handling, rust, option-type

I've written a "program" in Rust for reading integers from the console conveniently:

```
fn read_i32() -> Result<i32, String> {
  let mut input = String::new();
  match std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
    Ok(_) => match input.trim_end().parse::<i32>() {
      Ok(integer) => Ok(integer),
      Err(_) => Err(String::from("parsing failed"))
    },
    Err(_) => Err(String::from("reading failed"))
  }
}

fn main() {
  println!("{:?}", read_i32());
}
```

However, the error handling I'm using is obviously poor (coming from C++, I'm used to exceptions) and putting `String` as the `Err` version of my `Result` is probably just a hack. I want to

- read until any whitespace character, not only `'\n'`;
- avoid that explicit C-style error checking after each operation;
- use a better "error-type" for `read_i32()`.

How can it be achieved? `Result<i32, ParseIntError>` isn't generic enough because the problem can occur before parsing. `.map()` and other functional magic doesn't seem useful for starting it right after `read_line()` via a chain of `.`s (in my case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you define custom \`Error\` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584368/how-do-you-define-custom-error-types-in-rust)

Comment: "avoid that explicit C-style error checking after each operation;" you may wish to not use Rust...

Comment: @Stargateur it does help, only with one of the points though.

Comment: @Stargateur "you may wish not to use Rust" looking for the answer, I've seen `try!`, `?`, `.map()` etc. so I hope there's something convenient...

Comment: you say you don't want C-style error checking, you used match, C doesn't have this so you say "don't want error checking after each operation" and you opposite it to exception. ? try! are still "error checking after each operation" there are just shortcut. There is some crate that emulate some other way to do error checking in rust doing it implicitly. But I totally opposite to this style and I found it's not at all rusty. That why I suggest tu use an other language. The duplicate I linked answer all your points expect "avoid that explicit C-style error checking after each operation;".

Comment: @Stargateur I've listed three components of my problem, only one of them is discussed in the "duplicate". Please stop sending me away to learn another language: I understood your opinion about error handling, now let us see if someone comes up with a less verbose way (even if it still involves explicit yet short checks).

Comment: There isn’t any result tag. What the message probably means is that you haven’t got enough reputation to create it.

Comment: @OleV.V. oof really, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error-handling in Rust is something that is still evolving right now. You might be interested in this recent article https://nick.groenen.me/posts/rust-error-handling/ for some general, up-to-date suggestions and discussion.

Depending on how much structured information you want to preserve about the errors, there are several possible approaches. At one end of the spectrum, you could use [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/1.0.19/thiserror/) to construct your own precise error type:

```
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error("Parsing failed")]
    ParseError { source: std::num::ParseIntError },

    #[error("Reading failed")]
    ReadError { source: std::io::Error },
}

fn read_i32() -> Result<i32, MyError> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    match std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
        Ok(_) => match input.trim_end().parse::<i32>() {
            Ok(integer) => Ok(integer),
            Err(e) => Err(MyError::ParseError { source: e }),
        },
        Err(e) => Err(MyError::ReadError { source: e }),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", read_i32());
}
```

Another way, again using `thiserror`, is to embed the source errors directly into your error type using `#[from]`. This allows you to automatically convert to your error type using the `?` operator:

```
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error(transparent)]
    IOError(#[from] std::io::Error),

    #[error(transparent)]
    ParseIntError(#[from] std::num::ParseIntError),
}

fn read_i32() -> Result<i32, MyError> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?;
    let x = input.trim_end().parse::<i32>()?;
    Ok(x)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", read_i32());
}
```

This makes it easier to produce `MyError`s. The drawback here is that by doing it this way you give up some ability to add contextual information to your error type; for instance, if there were multiple places in your function where an `io::Error` could occur, then with the first approach your error type could include multiple variants to identify precisely where it occurred, along with other contextual information which you might want to add (such as the line number in the file where the error occurred); this ability is lost by just passing through the underlying `io::Error`.

On the other hand, if you know that the code that uses `read_i32` is not going to need any structured information about the type of error, and you just need to produce human-readable error messages, then there's no need to define a custom error type, and you could use the [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.31/anyhow/) crate like this, for example:

```
use anyhow::{Context, Result};

fn read_i32() -> Result<i32> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).context("Read failed")?;
    let x = input.trim_end().parse::<i32>().context("Parse failed")?;
    Ok(x)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", read_i32());
}
```

At the other end of the spectrum, if you don't even need those human-readable messages ("Read failed", "Parse failed"), then you could also just convert all the errors to a `Box<dyn Error>`:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn read_i32() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?;
    let x = input.trim_end().parse::<i32>()?;
    Ok(x)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", read_i32());
}
```

This may make the errors more difficult to interpret though, as your program grows, because this way they won't provide much context. One thing that's a little inconvenient right now is that it is not easy to get backtraces from Rust errors (at least not in stable Rust). This is something that's currently being worked on (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53487).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do I understand correctly that I need non-std libraries for your solutions except the last one? That's a pity because I liked the second one... I guess `trait From` can help me nonetheless, can't it?

Comment: Yes, Rust tends to be pretty conservative with what goes into `std`, especially with cases like this where the community is still experimenting with different approaches. Just about any non-trivial Rust project is going to need to pull in non-std crates. The nice thing is that `cargo` makes it pretty easy to pull in other crates: you just have to add one line to your `Cargo.toml`.