# Convert Result<_, error> to Result<_, MyError> with thiserror in Rust

Tags: rust, error-handling, thiserror

I'd like to implement a custom enum to wrap multiple errors like the code below.

I know I can make it work with `map_err` but it does not seem to be neat. And since `Result` is not defined in the current crate, I can't implement its conversion.

How will you deal with it in this situation?

Looking at `wrapped_fn`, it seems to implement `Result<_, io::Error>` conversion. Would you kindly tell me why this can work?

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use std::io;
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Debug, Error)]
enum MyError {
    #[error("CustomError {0}")]
    CustomError(#[from] io::Error),
}

struct MyStruct {}

fn error_fn() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "other"));
}

fn wrapped_fn() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    error_fn()?;  // no idea why this works because it seems like implement `Result` conversion.
    Ok(())
}


fn main() {
    let result: Result<(), MyError> = error_fn().into(); // I want to make this work.
    // let result: Result<(), MyError> = error_fn().map_err(MyError::from); // This works.
}

// This cannot be implemented as well.
// impl<T> std::convert::From<Result<T, io::Error>> for Result<T, MyError>{
//     fn from(result: io::Error) -> Self{
//         result.map_err(MyError::from)
//     }
// }
```

#### Error output

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Result<(), MyError>: From<Result<(), std::io::Error>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:50
   |
19 |     let result: Result<(), MyError> = error_fn().into();
   |                                                  ^^^^ the trait `From<Result<(), std::io::Error>>` is not implemented for `Result<(), MyError>`
   |
   = note: required for `Result<(), std::io::Error>` to implement `Into<Result<(), MyError>>`
```

Comment: Yes, part of it. Thanks.

Comment: Which part of the answer would be missing? The example function `wrapped_fn` kind of gives the answer away. The `?` operator takes care of converting the error via `From`, and your error type built using `thiserror` already implements `From<io::Error>` because it is annotated for that purpose (`#[from]`).

Comment: I want to make `error_fn().into();` work. Would `map_err` be the only answer?

Comment: Simply put, `error_fn().into()` won't work and is not how you do it. You would either call `map_err` or some extension method which returns a new `Result`. For instance, `snafu` provides `context` methods for encapsulating the error type into another one with added context. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62375381/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584368/how-do-you-define-custom-error-types-in-rust

Comment: I was trying to capture multiple errors from match context. So I wanted to know the way to complete this conversion. But now I am getting to think that I should use function instead of match context. It would be very nice and clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wrapped_fn` is what you typically want to do!  The [`?` is actually converting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try.html) `From` the existing error to the wanted error type before returning it if there is an error.

If you really want to do a conversion like the one in your `main` without returning the error, then I think the nice way to write it is indeed:

```
fn main() {
    let result = error_fn().map_err(MyError::from);
}
```