# rust program crashes when calling unwrap

Tags: rust

My simple rust program uses jsonpath crate to lookup some values in a json document.

The code that I am using is the following

```
use serde::Deserialize;

extern crate jsonpath;
extern crate serde_json;

use jsonpath::Selector;
use serde_json::Value;
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};

fn main() {
    let jsondoc = r#"
        {
          "a": 10,
          "b": "a string",
          "c" : false,
          "point" : {
            "x" : 1,
            "y": 2
          }
        }
    "#;


    let json: Value = serde_json::from_str(jsondoc).unwrap(); // Parse JSON document

    let selector1 = Selector::new("$.a").unwrap();  // Create a JSONPath selector
    let result1: Vec<f64> = selector1.find(&json)
        .map(|t| t.as_f64().unwrap())
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", result1);

    let selector2 = Selector::new("$.b").unwrap();  // Create a JSONPath selector
    let result2: Vec<&str> = selector2.find(&json)
        .map(|t| t.as_str().unwrap())
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", result2);

    let selector3 = Selector::new("$.c").unwrap();  // Create a JSONPath selector
    let result3: Vec<bool> = selector3.find(&json)
        .map(|t| t.as_bool().unwrap())
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", result3);

   
}
```

A concern is that if I change the json value "a" from 10 to "ten" (different data type) the code crashes in this statement: map(|t| t.as_f64().unwrap()) (cannot unwrap)

How do I protect the code in order to avoid panics?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: "How do I protect the code in order to avoid panics?", well, don't use `unwrap` and actually handle errors.

Comment: Unwrap panics if the result is an error. If this is not what you desire you need to manually handle the error instead.

Comment: See the [Result::unwrap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) documentation: "Because this function may panic, its use is generally discouraged." Typically, you should only use `.unwrap()` if you are *absolutely certain* that the value is `Ok(...)`.

Comment: understood, however I was asking how to avoid unwrap(), because it is certain that will fail, but maintain the expressiveness and readability of map > collect etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the problem here is that [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) panics on errors. The solution is to propagate your result around your program, bubbling it up until you want to handle it.

There's one complication, though: `as_*()` methods *don't* return a `Result`, but rather an `Option`. If we want to treat it as an error case and propogate it around the program, turning it into a `Result` will make that much nicer.

Here's a simple way to do that using [`ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or):

```rust
let selector3 = Selector::new("$.c").unwrap();  // Create a JSONPath selector
let result3: Vec<bool> = selector3.find(&json)
    .map(|t| t.as_bool().ok_or("expected boolean, found something else").unwrap())
    .collect();
println!("{:?}", result3);
```

If you want to make this error message better and/or include more information in it, I think making a custom error enum is probably the best solution. There's a lot of detail on that in [this answer to a related question about error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584607/1907543), but in short, if you create your own error type containing more information, you can easily make the errors much more readable:

```rust
use snafu::Snafu; // 0.6.8

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum MyError {
    #[snafu(display("expected {}, found {}", value))]
    WrongValueType {
        expected: &'static str,
        actual: serde_json::Value,
    }
}


let selector3 = Selector::new("$.c").unwrap();  // Create a JSONPath selector
let result3: Vec<bool> = selector3.find(&json)
    .map(|t| t.as_bool().ok_or_else(|| MyError::WrongValueType { expected: "boolean", actual: t.clone() }).unwrap())
    .collect();
println!("{:?}", result3);
```

This uses the [`snafu`](https://docs.rs/snafu/) crate, but there are other options (or it can be done manually). Again, see the above linked answer for more information.

Alright - we have a `Result`. Now, we need to propogate it up. This adds some boilerplate, but fortunately, it shouldn't have to change the style all that much. In particular, [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) can be used to collect into anything implementing [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html), and [`Result` implements `FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.44.0/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#method.from_iter-14).

Replacing each map with something like this will iterate until either all results are found `Ok()`, or one is an `Err`:

```rust
let selector3 = Selector::new("$.c").unwrap();  // Create a JSONPath selector
let result3: Vec<bool> = selector3.find(&json)
    .map(|t| t.as_bool().ok_or("expected boolean, found something else"))
    // &'static str is our error type
    .collect::<Result<Vec<bool>, &'static str>>()
    .unwrap();
println!("{:?}", result3);
```

We're still unwrapping, so it'll still panic, but that brings the error one step up. To deal with it at the top level, you'll need to stick this into a function returning a `Result` itself, and then match on that result to deal with the error case. It's a common pattern to do this by turning our main function into *just* error handling, and then to make our "real main" a separate function returning a `Result`. Here's an application of that on your snippet of code:

```rust
// `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` encapsulates "any error" without giving
// access to the details
fn try_main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let jsondoc = r#"
        {
          "a": 10,
          "b": "a string",
          "c" : false,
          "point" : {
            "x" : 1,
            "y": 2
          }
        }
    "#;


    let json: Value = serde_json::from_str(jsondoc)?; // Parse JSON document

    let selector1 = Selector::new("$.a").unwrap();  // Create a JSONPath selector
    let result1: Vec<f64> = selector1.find(&json)
        .map(|t| t.as_f64().ok_or("expected boolean, found something else"))
        .collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;
    println!("{:?}", result1);
    // ... remaining code can be translated as this one.
}

fn main() {
    match try_main() {
        Ok(()) => {}
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error occurred: {}", e);
            std::process::exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```