# Define function that can return multiple error types in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a `main()` function that returns `Result()`. In this function I'm running other functions that may return different error types. What is the best method to define all the error types?

Consider the following example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    CustomError
}

fn can_raise_custom_error() -> Result<(), Error> {
    Ok(())
}

fn can_raise_io_error() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<(), ???> {
    let _ = can_raise_custom_error()?;
    let _ = can_raise_io_error()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is to define the `io::Error` within my enum and use `match` expression to change `std::io::Error` to `Error:IoError`.
Is there any better way? I would expect something like combining traits, but it doesn't work:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), <Error + std::io::Error>> {
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584368/how-do-you-define-custom-error-types-in-rust

Comment: [Here's an example of using `From` with your custom error type to support automatic conversion from `std::io::Error`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=41089d4d5d95786052fb714a806e66e6), as suggested in the other question.

Comment: The `failure` crate and the `From` trait are both great solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Consider preferring `thiserror` over `failure`, as the former provides the same features and is already aligned with the latest Rust compiler.