# How to catch all errors in rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I am new to rust and I have wrote a function which returns a Result with Box dyn Error.

```
use std::error::Error;

fn func<T>(val: T) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    println!("{:?}", val);    
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    func("hello world");
}
```

Here I am not writing any error logic in the function `func` but it still works. Does the above code automatically catches all errors? similar to python's

```
try:
  # Run the code
except:
  # Catch all the errors
```

Is there any universal error catching way in rust?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run `cargo clippy` on this you will get the following warning:

```
warning: unused `std::result::Result` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     func("hello world");
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
```

this is telling you that although `func` returns a `Result` which could be an error, you are not doing anything with it.

You need to handle the error - the simplest way to do this is to just change main to return an error:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    func("hello world")?; // If this fails, the `?` makes main return it
    Ok(())
}
```

Now is `func` fails, `main` will fail too.

To see this in action we need an error type - which is a bit tedious to implement (for example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584368/how-do-you-define-custom-error-types-in-rust) for details). Instead, I'll just convert to using `anyhow` for errors.

```
use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};

fn func<T>(val: T) -> Result<()>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    println!("{:?}", val);    
    Err(anyhow!("BANG"))
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    func("hello world")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Now `func` returns an error, and running the binary outputs:

```
"hello world"
Error: BANG
```

If you don't want your application to exit on error, or don't want it to exit in this way, then you need to handle the result from `func` yourself

```
use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};

fn func<T>(val: T) -> Result<()>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    println!("{:?}", val);    
    Err(anyhow!("BANG"))
}

fn main() {
    match func("hello world") {
      Err(e) => println!("an error: {:?}", e), //<= error handling
      Ok(_) => println!("func was OK"),
    }
}
```

which will output:

```
"hello world"
an error: BANG
```